# d3-drag - rescale y-axis with drag in d3v5

Tags: d3.js, d3fc

I'm trying to achieve the effect of rescaling the d3fc cartesian chart when the user drags along the axes.

https://codepen.io/parliament718/pen/BaNQPXx

This is in d3v5, and I'm using d3-zoom to re-scale the axes using `d3.event.transform`. However, in d3-drag there is no `d3.event.transform` so I don't understand what the equivelant logic would be using just the mouse coordinates that d3-drag provides.

```
const zoom = d3.zoom()
   .on('zoom', () => {
       const t = d3.event.transform;
       x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
       y.domain(t.rescaleY(y2).domain());
       render();
   });

plot.call(zoom);

//What is the equivelant drag action to rescale?
const yAxisDrag = d3.drag()                 
    .on('end', (args) => {
       var t = d3.zoomTransform(plot.node());

       //zoom.translateBy(plot,d3.event.dx/t.k,d3.event.dy/t.k);
       //How can I use zoom.scaleBy() here instead?
    });
```

Comment: have you considered adding the zoom listener only, or additionally, to the axes, rather than just the plot, which provide conventional zoom event mojo?

Comment: What would that accomplish? Zoom behavior pans when dragging. That is the d3-drag equivelant of the code proposed in a now deleted answer: ```d3.drag().on("drag",() => { const t = d3.zoomTransform(plot.node()); zoom.translateBy(plot,d3.event.dx/t.k,d3.event.dy/t.k); });```
Instead, I need scaling when dragging. d3-drag seems like the proper thing to use and I think it's similar to the code above except using scaleBy method. I just dont understand the logic of transforming x/y points into an axis rescale. To clarify, the behavior I want can be seen on any chart on TradingView.com

Comment: ok, if you *need* dragging instead of mousewheel or whatever, then that settles it.  To transform x/y into new scale, you can use [d3.scale.invert](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#continuous_invert).  You pass the `x` or `y` range (i.e., pixel) value to `invert` on the original scale, and it returns the domain value, which you can then pass to the `rescale` function.

Comment: What rescale function? I only see a rescaleX and rescaleY that take a scale, not a domain as a paramter. Could you please demonstrate what you mean in the provided codepen?

Comment: i thought about this a bit more.  I was thinking you would take the x or y position at the drag end and use that to calculate scale--but as you likely know there would need to be an interim step to determine what to scale by.  That led me to think you could either programmatically call zoom from the drag end handler, perhaps using a `scaleBy` value to determine the scaling factor.  OTOH, is use of a `brush` on the axes a viable alternative? There are myriad examples. If not using a brush directly, maybe the brush source could illuminate a solution?

Comment: Thanks but I'm not really following your thought process here. Please provide an example. I've prepared a codepen for this reason.

Comment: @varontron I've started a bounty for this question if you want to give it a shot at correcting my codepen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create another zoom behavior which only changes the Y domain. Then, in the drag handler, call the new behavior's `scaleBy` on the plot area with a scale factor based on the drag event's delta Y:

```js
const yAxisZoom = d3.zoom()
  .on('zoom', () => {
    y.domain(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y2).domain());
    render();
  });

const yAxisDrag = d3.drag()
  .on('drag', () => {
    const factor = Math.pow(2, -d3.event.dy * 0.01);
    d3.select('#zoom-chart .plot-area').call(yAxisZoom.scaleBy, factor);
  });
```